Old movie were a Gregory Peck-like actor jests about "the Brownies"
I remember an old (B&W? - not sure) film I saw as a television re-run, probably between late 1960's, in which a character played by Gregory Peck or an actor that reminds me of Gregory Peck jests about the (mythical) Brownies that come out at night.
The scene was indoors in a house or apartment, the man may have been seated, and I believe he was speaking to a woman. The mood was light, one of those up-beat music, clever dialogue, happy ending films like Designing Women (1957) perhaps.
I only have memory of this few-second vignette.
Need help identifying the movie.
Background on The Brownies.

above: from here.

Please try to add anything that may help identification. Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions of scenes or names of characters or actors you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question.

@Paulie_D I understand how helpful it would be, and I certainly wouldn't be holding anything back here. I recall only a few seconds, I saw this a very, very long time ago. The only reason I even remember this is my surprise to find out that my father hadn't been making up the "existence" of Brownies himself.

@Paulie_D have added some items, not sure I can say I've added "information" though.
